# Django CSRF token not in request cookies

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django and Django Rest Framework and facing an error where the system is no longer setting a CSRF Token in the request cookies

My Middleware class:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)
```

This is a very sudden error and it was working till about an hour or so ago and there have been no changes in the code. I restarted my server and the request cookies dont have `csrftoken` in them anymore.

Comment: Are you sure you are not using csrf exempt in your view?

Comment: You should probably be looking at the response Set-Cookie headers rather than the request cookies - request cookies just tell you that your browser isn't sending them anymore.

Comment: What CSRF related settings do you have in your settings file?